# Does the execution order of instructions matter if the register-states are the same?

Tags: qemu, execution, control-flow, instructions

The effect an executed instruction has depends on the current registers it is working with. For example, an instruction that adds the content of 2 registers has the same effect when the content of the 2 registers are the same.

Now let's consider the execution of a program: The execution of a program can be described by the instructions executed along with the content of the registers these instructions used.

**My question**: I have a dump of every single instruction that was executed during the execution of a program along with the register values each instruction used. Is the order that these instructions are executed at important?
Example:
I have two program-dumps. Each program-dump consists of the instructions(1-4) along with the register-states(A-D) each instruction used.
Can i say that both runs of the program are equivalent if the instructions get executed in a different order? (top to bottom, notice how in the second run the instruction 2 is executed after instruction 3 but the register-states the instructions have in both runs are the same).

```
Run 1:               Run2:
 1 A                  1 A
 2 B                  3 C
 3 C                  2 B
 4 D                  4 D
```

**Background**: I am comparing the native execution of a program with the exection by qemu (emulator). When looking at the dumps, i noticed that some things get executed in a different order when the same program is run by qemu. Also some instructions get executed natively that dont get executed by qemu and vice versa. So when comparing, can i just check if an instruction that got executed had the same register-states in the other dump or is this completely wrong?

Comment: Only if those instructions operate exclusively on registers, and you're tracking all of them (including flags etc.). If memory (or any sort of I/O instructions) are in there, tracking only registers isn't enough.

Comment: Usually the observable effect of a program is produced only by those instructions that perform I/O, system calls, etc.  Suppose you have an instruction that outputs the contents of register A, and it is executed once with `A=0` and once with `A=1`.  The order determines whether the program outputs `10` or `01`, which are obviously not equivalent.

Comment: @Mat yes i am tracking all user-space registers including flags. And these instructions do not operate exclusively on registers, these dumps are from normal executables that may do anything. (exampe: /bin/ls under linux). Is there still a way to compare both dumps (see background) and say that x% of instructions are the same? Because from this knowledge now, if there is a difference in the first few instructions, i cannot compare the other millions of instructions.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve exactly? Any change in order or kind of operations can lead to vastly different results. Why are you comparing instruction streams rather than outputs/effects?

Comment: @Mat i am trying to tell if the execution of qemu differs from the native execution and if so (it does) say by how much it differs